# Unable to Center content on zoom out

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using absolute positioning on almost every element of the website. It is working perectly 
however only issue that I am having is that when I zoom out the footer remains nicely centererd but the header(`#header`) and content(`#content`) move towards left side. I am using margin:auto and even tried to center both of them using Jquery but the problem remains there. So can any one give me a solution. I would be grateful.

Here is the Site:http://contestlancer.com/Trivia/

Comment: Your `footer` div is `position: relative`

Comment: Could you please add a short but working piece of sample markup and css? That way when you fix your linked site this question can still be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Hello I would love to but problem is that the css is specific to the site e.g left :220px etc. I don't think it can help any other person as it is specific case

Answer (score 0):

You should put your div having id "aside" and "righter" in a wrapper div and give auto margin to wrapper div.

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:1024px;" > 
   <div id="aside"> </div>    
   <div id="righter"> </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem at all. Makes no difference.






















 <a href=http://download.cnet.com/Free-Youtube-Downloader-Pro/3000-2071_4-75329731.html >youtube downloader</a>

Answer (score 0):

When using `position:absolute`, you basically take over full control on positioning, which makes layout a big job, because you don't leave anything to the browser.

- Use `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute` where used.
- Use `top:0px;' on both`#content`and`#footer`.
- Use % for left margin and widths of the top sections in `#header` and `#content`, like it's already done in `#footer`.

Example for `#content`:

```css
#aside
{
  top: 30px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #F7B800;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 15%;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;    
}

#righter {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  top: 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 550px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 5%;    
}
```

One important thing is that `margin-left`, `margin-right` and `width` of the two sections add up to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect your website using firebug it shows that `#logo`, `#navigation`, `#righter` and `#aside` have a set `margin-left: ...px` in pixels.

This means they will ALWAYS have a left margin of the set amount of pixels even when you zoom out or in. Try working with percentages instead. ie:

```
#righter {
   left: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do, when there's bull load of scrambled css and html mix, then I'll force it with jquery:

```
var w = $(window),
    el = $('#elementIwantToCenter');

//when first viewing the site => center el horizontally
el.css({position: 'absolute', left: (w.width()-parseFloat(el.css('width')))/2});

//when resizing browser window => center el horizontally
w.resize(function() {
  el.css({left: ($(this).width()-parseFloat(el.css('width')))/2});
});
w.trigger('resize');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/XSDM7/